# cURL alternative; cURL not supported and I will not be able to enable it

Tags: php, html, http, curl, paypal

I've finished my university project from home using a WAMP server. I use a cUrl command when processing a paypal payment. Now I'm copying the project to the university servers I've found that cURL is not supported. Is there a work around for this code?

```
  // Set the curl parameters.
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

  // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
  $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

  // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

  // Get response from the server.
  $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: are the  fopen wrappers enabled on the server?

Comment: I have no control over the server at all. I can only upload files to a domain

Comment: Listen to what Dagon is saying.  If you've got fopen wrappers, you can specify URLs in fopen and treat URLs like files...  actually try this b/c it might solve your problem (and be a lot easier than what you already have there)

Comment: fopen or file_get_conents

Comment: Except it seems OP is using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: @BobNocraz shouldn't be an issue AFAIK paypal uses an fopen exampling for IPN response for PHP

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what fopen is, do you mind explaining?